# How do I show all of my markers in googlemaps android?

Tags: android, google-maps, zooming

I have an array of latitude and longitude points. I use them to make markers on the map. What can I do to show all of the markers on the map at the same time. eg make a good fit so that if the markers are within a city I zoom it in to only show the city and not the whole state, country etc...

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this might help

```
private void centerGroup(int groupId){
    if(groupId>0){
        int minLat = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int maxLat = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        int minLon = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int maxLon = Integer.MIN_VALUE;


        Cursor cursor = getYourLantLongs(groupId);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
            final int LAT_INDEX = cursor.getColumnIndex(T.Waypoints.LATITUDE);
            final int LON_INDEX = cursor.getColumnIndex(T.Waypoints.LONGITUDE);

            do {
                final int lat = (int) (cursor.getFloat(LAT_INDEX)*1E6);
                final int lon = (int) (cursor.getFloat(LON_INDEX)*1E6);

                maxLat = Math.max(lat, maxLat);
                minLat = Math.min(lat, minLat);
                maxLon = Math.max(lon, maxLon);
                minLon = Math.min(lon, minLon);

            } while(cursor.moveToNext());


            mapController.zoomToSpan(Math.abs(maxLat - minLat), Math.abs(maxLon - minLon));
            mapController.animateTo(new GeoPoint((maxLat + minLat)/2, (maxLon + minLon)/2 ));

            /*
            final int cLat =  (int)((maxLat*1E6 + minLat*1E6)/2);
            final int cLon =  (int)((maxLon*1E6 + minLon*1E6)/2);

            final int zLat =  (int)Math.abs(maxLat - minLat);
            final int zLon =  (int)Math.abs(maxLon - minLon);

            //mapController.zoomToSpan(zLat, zLon);
            mapController.animateTo(new GeoPoint(cLat, cLon));
             */
        }
    }           
}
```

in short you make a square and zoom in.

Comment: I was thinking about this but I didn't realize there was a zoomtospan feature. This is great thanks a lot!

Comment: PS. consider changing mapView to MapController mapController=mapView.getontroller(), it was a little confusing when I didnt find the zoomtospan feature in the mapview class.

Comment: ah, that was an omission in edit while copy-paste! and i was using a mapview-proxy. i have changed it to mapController.

Answer (score 1):

Go through your array and save min and max values of latitude and longitude.
Then use

```
mMapController.zoomToSpan((maxLatitude - minLatitude), (maxLongitude - minLongitude));
```

to get the right zoom level. And

```
mMapController.animateTo(new GeoPoint(

                                (maxLatitude + minLatitude)/2 ,

                                (maxLongitude + minLongitude)/2 ));
```

to move the map to the center of your markers.

Have fun!